# uploadify Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with uploadify.

Chrome gives me the following error when I try to use uploadify: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Here is my html:

```html
<li id="avatarUploadContainer">
  <div id="avatarUploaderDiv" style="position: relative; margin-top: 10px;">
    <input id="avatarUploader" name="avatarUploader" type="file" buttonText="upload">
  </div>
</li>
```

Here is my javascript to initialize uploadify:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#country').change(function() {
    var countryID = $(this).val();
    getStateList(countryID);
  });


  /*
   * Include flash uploader for avatar uploading
   */

  $('#avatarUploader').click(function(){
    var uploaderPath = baseURL + '/actions.php?action=updateAccountInfo&mode=avatarUpload&umem_id=' + $('#umem_id').val() + '&ms_id=' + $('#membership_id').val();
    var buttonText = $('#avatarUploader').attr('buttonText');
    var fileExt = '.jpg;';
    console.log(uploaderPath);
    console.log(buttonText);
    console.log(fileExt);
    $("#avatarUploader").uploadify({
      'formData': {
        'securityTimestamp': $('#securityTimestamp').val(),
        'securityToken': $('#securityToken').val()
      },
      'height': 14,
      'swf': baseURL + '/assets/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
      'uploader': uploaderPath,
      'multi': false,
      'buttonText': buttonText,
      'folder': baseURL + "/assets/avatars/",
      'fileTypeDesc': 'Images',
      'fileTypeExts': fileExt,
      'fileSizeLimit': $('#maxUploadSize').val(),
      'width': 146,
      'preventCaching': true,


      'onQueueComplete': function(queueData) {

        $('#editorAvatar').attr('src', baseURL + '/avatar.php?size=150&memID=' + $('#mem_id').val());
        $('#memNavAvatar').attr('src', baseURL + '/avatar.php?size=100&memID=' + $('#mem_id').val());

      }
    });

  });
});
```

My php doesn't even get executed as far as I have tested.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You probably meant to write `if ($('#avatarUploader').length) {`. With `if ($('#avatarUploader')) {` the condition always evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Thanks PeterKA, I edited the code and changed the if statement to $('#avatarUploader').click(function(). I have to fix another guys code, however I still get the following error in firebug: TypeError: f[e] is undefined. 
 

... e in f){if(f.hasOwnProperty(e)){d.push(encodeURIComponent(e.toString())+"="+enc...

Comment: This are very basic and easy mistakes. On which line do you get this error? The object you are using on that line is not defined.

Comment: line 16 and col 17782 of jquery.uploadify-3.1.min.js, so the uploadify library... I have updated to the new version of uploadify, just renamed it to jquery.uploadify-3.1.min.js with no success

Answer (score 1):

your problem might be solved already, but anyway...
this error might occur, if the Form Data contains invalid Data Fields.

To be more specific: either `$('#securityTimestamp').val()` or `$('#securityToken').val()` might be undefined.

```
'formData': {
        'securityTimestamp': $('#securityTimestamp').val(),
        'securityToken': $('#securityToken').val()
      },
```